# Group GeoJson features by property value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop, geojson

I have a list of geojson features that each have an asset ID in their properties. I want to manipulate the geojson so I am left with only a single feature per asset ID, with the properties from each feature found added to the feature properties.

As an example, the following geojson has 4 features; 2 of them have an asset ID of 100 and 2 of them have an asset ID of 200:-

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "title":"map_features",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               525408,
               162788
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "CASENO":"CASE29302",
            "CASE_TYPE":"litterBin",
            "ASSETID":"100",
            "DESCRIPTION":"Bin is full"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               525408,
               162788
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "CASENO":"CASE56843",
            "CASE_TYPE":"litterBin",
            "ASSETID":"100",
            "NOTES":"Bin needs emptying"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               525177,
               164509
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "CASENO":"CASE77112",
            "CASE_TYPE":"litterBin",
            "ASSETID":"200",
            "NOTES":"Bin cleaned"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               525177,
               164509
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "CASENO":"CASE04393",
            "CASE_TYPE":"litterBin",
            "ASSETID":"200",
            "NOTES":"Bin full"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I am looking to be left with just two features for asset ID 100 and 200, and have the properties grouped together from the duplicate features:-

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "title": "map_features",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    525408,
                    162788
                ]
            },
            "properties": [
                {
                    "CASENO": "CASE29302",
                    "CASE_TYPE": "litterBin",
                    "ASSETID": "100",
                    "DESCRIPTION": "Bin is full"
                },
                {
                    "CASENO": "CASE56843",
                    "CASE_TYPE": "litterBin",
                    "ASSETID": "100",
                    "NOTES": "Bin needs emptying"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    525408,
                    162788
                ]
            },
            "properties": [
                {
                    "CASENO": "CASE56843",
                    "CASE_TYPE": "litterBin",
                    "ASSETID": "100",
                    "NOTES": "Bin needs emptying"
                },
                {
                    "CASENO": "CASE04393",
                    "CASE_TYPE": "litterBin",
                    "ASSETID": "200",
                    "NOTES": "Bin full"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure if there is a javascript / jquery method that might help with this? Would I need to use a for loop?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Always grouping by `ASSETID`? Also, second `Feature`'s coordinates are not correct, ain't it?

Comment: I think just making an array of the of the properties (simple).

Comment: Pointer: Of course you would need a for loop, pushing to a `result = {}` object as you go. The `result` also should be inner iterated looking for matching item with item.properties[0].ASSETID (If not exists, create an array of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're confident that the duplicate features have the same geometry you can use this approach:

1. Group the features by `ASSETID` you can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with `reduce` to do this where each key is a unique `ASSETID` and the value is an array that fills up with features.
2. For each item in the `Map`, use the first feature in the array for the `geometry` and then for `properties` replace the array of features with an array of just the `properties`.
3. Create a new `featureCollection` with the new features resolved in step 2.

See the comments in the working code below:

```js
// group features by ASSETID
const assets = Array.from(
  fc.features.reduce((a, c) => {
    const id = c.properties.ASSETID;
    if (!a.has(id)) a.set(id, []); // <-- initialise each entry with an empty array
    a.get(id).push(c);             // <-- add the feature to the array for that ASSETID
    return a;
  }, new Map())                    // <-- the accumulator is a Map
);

// create new features
const newFeatures = assets.reduce((a, c) => {
  a.push({
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": c[1][0].geometry,  // <-- take geometry from first array entry
    "properties": c[1].map(f => f.properties) // <-- just retain the properties of the feature
  });
  return a;
}, []);

// create new feature collection
const newFc = {
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "title":"map_features",
   "features": newFeatures
}

// output
console.log(newFc);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
const fc = {
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "title":"map_features",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               525408,
               162788
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "CASENO":"CASE29302",
            "CASE_TYPE":"litterBin",
            "ASSETID":"100",
            "DESCRIPTION":"Bin is full"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               525408,
               162788
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "CASENO":"CASE56843",
            "CASE_TYPE":"litterBin",
            "ASSETID":"100",
            "NOTES":"Bin needs emptying"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               525177,
               164509
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "CASENO":"CASE77112",
            "CASE_TYPE":"litterBin",
            "ASSETID":"200",
            "NOTES":"Bin cleaned"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               525177,
               164509
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "CASENO":"CASE04393",
            "CASE_TYPE":"litterBin",
            "ASSETID":"200",
            "NOTES":"Bin full"
         }
      }
   ]
}
</script>
```